# Is there a simulator for tvOS?

Tags: xcode, tvos

Is there a simulator for tvOS?

All I've got as part of a default project is "Generic tvOS Device"

[image: Generic tvOS]

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: this is Xcode 7.1 right?

Comment: Yes, this is in 7.1 beta

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is what you should see:

[image]

You could try reading through [this apple developer forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16937?q=tvos) (login required), as it appears it's a similar issue.

Comment: I re-installed and the simulator magically appeared. Seems to be a 7.1 beta bug

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1:** XCode 7.1 > Window > Devices

[image: XCode 7.1 > Window > Devices]

**Step 2:** Tap + button (Bottom left)

[image: Tap + button (Bottom left)]

**Step 3:** Select Device Type: Apple TV 1080p

[image: Select Device Type: Apple TV 1080p]

**Step 4:** Create

**Step 5:** Restart XCode (most important)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, make sure that `TARGETED_DEVIDE_FAMILY` is set to `3` in our Apple TV target. Apparently Xcode does not set that by default... *How's that for an implementation detail?*

Comment: 3 is not even a choice in my XCode. 2 is the highest option.

Comment: This is also the correct answer, if you're adding Target manually to an iOS project.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simulator for it. If you create a new App using Xcode 7.1, you will get a choice of project template. Choose tvOS:

[image]

which comes with a simulator

Comment: He said that he already created the default tvOS project. I'm having the same problem.